# How can I add a line to one of the facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(all, aes(x=area, y=nq)) +
  geom_point(size=0.5) +
  geom_abline(data = levelnew, aes(intercept=log10(exp(interceptmax)), slope=fslope)) + #shifted regression line
  scale_y_log10(labels = function(y) format(y, scientific = FALSE)) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) + 
  facet_wrap(~levels) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))
```

And I get this figure

[image]

Now I want to add **one geom_line** to one of the facets. Basically, I wanted to have a dotted line (Say x=10,000) in only the **major** panel. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe you could try adding another geom_abline() but with a dataset with only data for the major panel....

Comment: I just have a simple equation to plot: Basically y=x+1 on the major panel

Comment: One option is to create a second dataframe, such asa suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846295/how-to-add-different-lines-for-facets

Comment: I think that is adding a line to all facets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a segment only to one facet using ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578352/add-a-segment-only-to-one-facet-using-ggplot2)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I made some up:

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),z=rep(letters[1:4],each=25))

ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~z)
```

[image]

To add a vertical line at `x = 1` we can use `geom_vline()` with a dataframe that has the same faceting variable (in my case `z='b'`, but yours will be `levels='major'`):

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~z) +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(xint=1,z="b"), aes(xintercept = xint), linetype = "dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Was hard to find. Should have made it red maybe.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to express this which is possibly easier to generalize (and formatting stuff left out):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ z) +
  geom_vline(data = subset(df, z == "b"), aes(xintercept = 1))
```

The key things being: facet first, then decorate facets by subsetting the original data frame, and put the details in a new `aes` if possible. Other examples of a similar idea:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ z) +
  geom_vline(data = subset(df, z == "b"), aes(xintercept = 1)) + 
  geom_smooth(data = subset(df, z == "c"), aes(x, y), method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = subset(df, z == "d"), aes(x = -2, y=0, label = "Foobar"))
```